# Ember data "no mapping" error, despite having a properly named model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Learning Ember, and I'm attempting to load a "blog post" from the server. I have the routes working, the REST request is made properly, and my server (node/express/mongoose) is returning the data properly.

However, ember complains:

> Assertion Failed: Your server returned a hash with the key page but you have no mapping for it

Based on all my research, this should work just fine.

The model code:

```
  App.Page = DS.Model.extend({
    slug: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    content:  DS.attr('string')
  });
```

The route's model connection:

```
App.PageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('page', {slug:params.slug});
  }
});
```

When the route loads, this is the JSON response from the server:

```
{
  "page":{
    "slug":"bbb",
    "title":"bbb",
    "content":"bbb"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do your Json results have an ID field?

Comment: Could you create jsbin prototype from your code sample? I tried to build it myself, but I can't repeat that assertion error. You can get my example as basis for your experimentations: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mudeto/2/edit?html,js,output. By the way, I tried to reveal the difference between finding by param (not id) and finding record by id in ember-data (see the example in jsbin).

Comment: It's bower. Running `bower install ember-data` installs version 0.14... `ember-data#0.0.14`, yet the version your example uses is `1.0.0-beta.10+canary.30d6bf849b`. When I use this locally, I'm no longer seeing any errors. I had to run `bower install ember-data#1.0.0-beta.10`

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with my code:

- `bower install ember-data` didn't install the latest version, I had to use `bower install ember-data#1.0.0-beta.10`
- Using `this.store.find('page', {slug:'bbb'});` apparently makes ember assume there will be more than one record returned - so it fails to accept any single record. I have to use the id syntax instead: `return this.store.find('page', 'bbb');`
- Once I was properly "querying" for a single record, I had to ensure that record JSON had an `id` property: `{"page":{"id":"54345c895b24bfc4df34cf86","slug":"bbb","title":"bbb","content":"bbb"}}`

Once I solved all three of those issues, I'm seeing my single record returning properly.